# Linq query converting to bool?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

How Can I get a bool back from the below linq query? I need to compare each deal target property and totalDealsCompleted property and if any deal targets are less than the total deals completed then set  HasEachTeamMemberHitTarget to false.I get a an error when building the below code on the if statment. I'm doing this in c#, mvc.

```
for (int i = 0; i < this.Select(m => m.EmployeeID).Count(); i++)
{

    if (this.Select (m => m.DealTarget < m.TotalDealsCompleted))
    {
        HasEachTeamMemberHitTarget = false;
        break;
    }

    else
    {
        HasEachTeamMemberHitTarget = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: post error which is coming??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
HasEachTeamMemberHitTarget = this.All(m => m.DealTarget < m.TotalDealsCompleted);
```

Comment: Yep thats what I wanted, thank you

Comment: @user3884462: i haven't mentioned it above, it replaces the whole loop.

Comment: That's great thanks little bit cleaner as well, thanks